# What Determines What Blackguard (Not Player) Bases

Tags: boom-beach

The player bases on the archipelago are determined by how many Victory Points you have as said in the Boom Beach Wiki. Yet there is no information on NPC Blackguard Bases. They seem to be determined by level or by something or I could have level 60 Blackguard bases on my map...

What determines what NPC Blackguard Bases can be found in your archipelago?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the forums:

http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/223251-Boom-Beach-Frequently-Asked-Questions-Read-BEFORE-Posting

> **How does NPC Matchmaking work?** You get new NPC opponents, referred to as Blackguard bases in game, when exploring the map and as
>   occasional invasions on your map. Your opponents are selected by a
>   matchmaking process that attempts to give you the right level of
>   challenge. Unlike your Player Matchmaking, your NPC Matchmaking score
>   does NOT decrease. As you defeat the NPC bases, increasingly more
>   difficult ones will spawn.

So in fact it isn't bound to your level or VP. :)